# Wrapping fields into additional JSON object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What is a good way to change the structure of JSON returned by Django Rest Framework's default model serialiers?

Example -

Restaurant object which is returned by DRF right now:

```
{
    "id":9,
    "label":"Pizza Hut"
    "like_id:":32,
    "like_quantity":2
}
```

More desirable json structure:

```
{
    "id":9,
    "label":"Pizza Hut",
    "social": {
       "like_id:":32,
       "like_quantity":2   
    }
}
```

To make the json structure, I want few fields from the default JSON be nested under a new field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better solution to me is to use `SerializerMethod` in your `Serializer`. For example:

```
class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')    
    label = serializers.CharField(source='label')
    social = serializers.SerializerMethod(method_name='pick_social_fields')

    def is_restaurant_liked(self, restaurant):
        # some logic here
        return is_liked

    def pick_social_fields(self, restaurant):
        like_id = self.is_restaurant_liked(restaurant)
        like_quantity = restaurant.like_set.count
        return {
            'like_id': like_id,
            'like_quantity': like_quantity
        }
```

This solution is better for me since you do not have to override anything in DRF Views. You only need to define a method in `Serializer` class.

Answer (score 3):

If you I get you right, you want this:

```
{
    "id":9,
    "label":"Pizza Hut",
    "social": {
       "like_id:":32,
       "like_quantity":2   
    }
}
```

to be result of GET request.

You can edit return values inside your Generic view, if you are using one, eg:

```
class RestaurantViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, 
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RestaurantSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
        restaurant = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = RestaurantSerializer(user,context={'request': request})
        results = {
                   "id":serializer.data['id'],
                   "label":serializer.data['label'],
                   "social": {
                        "like_id:":serializer.data['like_id'],
                        "like_quantity":serializer.data['like_quantity']   
                              }
                   }
        return Response(results)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this looks a little bit 'hacky'. I have crafted my own solution (see it below). Thanks again.